# How to rename downloaded file in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, file-rename

is there some way how to rename downloaded file in test?

Was looking for advice on google, but did not find any.

Current code to download load file:

```
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .btn').contains(domData.dwnldContractFiles).as('dwnldContractFiles').should('exist').should('be.visible').and('not.be.disabled')
    cy.get('@dwnldContractFiles').click()
    cy.verifyDownload(domData.allFiles, {timeout: 30000, interval: 3000})
```

Comment: Post your current code that downloads the file.

Comment: @art see my code in original question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cypress-downloadfile` if you are not tied to any download mechanism.
In order to install this package you need ti`npm install cypress-downloadfile`

Then add the following line to cypress/support/commands.js.

```
require('cypress-downloadfile/lib/downloadFileCommand');
```

Update your cypress.config.js file with:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const {downloadFile} = require('cypress-downloadfile/lib/addPlugin')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
         on('task', {downloadFile})
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Finally, you can use it in your tests and set any name you want:

```
cy.downloadFile('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg','downloads',chosenName)
```

Comment: I added my code to question, check that